# How do I create an Android make file to merge a glibc based root filesystem into to the AOSP filesystem?

Tags: makefile, android-source, glibc, android-soong

Appendix A (Legacy User-Space) of the 2013 Karim Yaghmour book [Embedded Android](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/embedded-android/9781449327958/) describes how to merge a root filesystem based on glibc that contains BusyBox into the AOSP build. But it describes how to make this work in 2.3/Gingerbread.

I'm trying to do the same for the [Android 8.1 sources provided](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-2ZsmvpGrdBQcbMrJVvkzp-Vrops2M4Q) with the [Orange Pi 4 LTS](http://www.orangepi.org/html/hardWare/computerAndMicrocontrollers/details/orange-pi-4-LTS.html).

Following the instructions in the book, I copied my cross-compiled build of a root filesystem based on glibc that contains BusyBox to a new directory in my AOSP:

```
$ ls -lh ~/builds/RK3399-Android8.1/rootfs-glibc
total 20K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 joe joe  584 Mar 18 12:14 Android.mk
drwxrwxr-x 2 joe joe 4.0K Mar  8 12:25 bin
drwxrwxr-x 2 joe joe 4.0K Mar  8 11:29 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 joe joe   11 Mar  8 12:25 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
drwxrwxr-x 2 joe joe 4.0K Mar  8 12:25 sbin
drwxrwxr-x 5 joe joe 4.0K Mar  8 11:30 usr
```

And I created an `Android.mk` file matching the one in the book. But it didn't work, so I experimented and adapted it to this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := rootfs-glibc
# LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := EXECUTABLES

# This part is a hack, we're doing "addprefix" because if we don't,
# this dependency will be stripped out by the build system
GLIBC_ROOTFS := $(addprefix $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/, rootfs-glibc)

$(GLIBC_ROOTFS):
    xxxmkdir -p $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)
    cp -af $(TOPDIR)rootfs-glibc/* $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)
    rm $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/Android.mk
    # The last command just gets rid of this very .mk since it's copied as is

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

I know the makefile is getting parsed since I was getting error messages before I added `LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS`. But the rules in my `$(GLIBC_ROOTFS)` target aren't getting run--confirmed by my deliberate change of `mkdir` to `xxxmkdir`.

I did some more research and learned about the existence of the [Soong Build System](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build), which was "introduced in Android 7.0 (Nougat) to replace Make." But I've searched for example `Android.bp` files to do something approximating what I'm trying to do with no success.

It appears I need to use a module type of [android_filesystem](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/11590307/linux/latest/view/soong_build.html), but I haven't found an example or clear enough documentation to create my own.

Should I fix my `Android.mk` file? How? Or should I use an `Android.bp` file?

Comment: android_filesystem type seems to have appeared in Android 12. Documentation does not seem to be much written but can you take a look at the test file for reference? https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-12.0.0_r34:build/soong/filesystem/filesystem_test.go Also, while searching this, I came up some examples within Virtualisation Module of A12 and higher
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Virtualization/+/refs/heads/android12-qpr3-s7-release/microdroid/Android.bp#215 Is this any relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to Karim Yaghmour who was kind to answer. He referred me to the exercises in his Embedded Android Training courseware. Go to [www.opersys.com/training/embedded-android-training](https://www.opersys.com/training/embedded-android-training/) and scroll down. Click on COURSEWARE. (Note the license.) There is a link of the right to the exercises. On page 14 are instructions for downloading an Android.mk file that worked for me (after following the accompanying instructions).